# Quartz Scheduler used in .Net Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, quartz-scheduler

Hello fellow Stackoverflowers,

I'm currently trying to integrate a way to schedule some database checks and database oriented operations that would take place everyday and process during the night at around 01:00 AM. I stumbled upon .NET Library Quartz and it seem to respond to my needs, but again I might be wrong.

I took the time to read their documentation, but I have a few questions still. They don't seem to cover the integration of this library in a website environment (from what I saw, it was mostly console-driven app).

1) Regarding website integration, I have seen a bit of code where the initialization was done in the Application_Start event of a Global.cs file. This seems to be close my needs, but then again, doesn't this mean that: **Each time a user/visitor visits my website, a new instance of scheduler will be created?**

> The Application_Start and Application_End methods are special methods that do not represent HttpApplication events. ASP.NET calls them once for the lifetime of the application domain, not for each HttpApplication instance.
>
> The Application_Start method is called only one time during the life cycle of an application.

2) Considering the fact that I want my job to execute 'only Once' BUT everyday at about 01:00 AM, I'm not sure I fully understand the concept of scheduling a process to runs constantly without stopping. Is Quartz really what I need to use for this?

3) Let's say my website is idle and no one visits it for two weeks (a bit far-fetched I know). Would my process still execute daily if I'm using Quartz?

I don't know if these questions are vague, and I don't expect (nor want) someone to give me the entire solution, but I just need guidance and knowledge to give me some insight on where to start with this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Regarding website integration, I have seen a bit of code where the initialization was done in the Application_Start event of a Global.cs file. This seems to be close my needs, but then again, doesn't this mean that: Each time a user/visitor visits my website, a new instance of scheduler will be created?
**Answer:**
You have given the answer for this

```
The Application_Start and Application_End methods are special methods that do not represent HttpApplication events. ASP.NET calls them once for the lifetime of the application domain, not for each HttpApplication instance.

The Application_Start method is called only one time during the life cycle of an application
```

The application start gets called only once so there wont be multiple instances of your scheduler

2) Considering the fact that I want my job to execute 'only Once' BUT everyday at about 01:00 AM, I'm not sure I fully understand the concept of scheduling a process to runs constantly without stopping. Is Quartz really what I need to use for this?

**Answer:** If you don't want to go for a sql based scheduler or setting a timer, Quartz.net is the best bet

3) Let's say my website is idle and no one visits it for two weeks (a bit far-fetched I know). Would my process still execute daily if I'm using Quartz?

**Answer:** The scheduler will continue working irrespective of sessions accessing your application (once its triggered) until and unless you stop IIS

Comment: Hello Karthik, thank you for your answer. So if I sum up: the Application Start event is were I need to place my code for it to execute. It will start once, regardless of the number of persons who access my website. It will keep on going and processing everyday, unless the App in IIS is restarted or stopped. Is this right?

Comment: Great! Then i will start coding and testing right away! thank you so much for your help! I will mark your answer as accepted!